# Trying to retrieve value from environment file getting undefined in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

Hi all i have set the variable in environment file like as below

```
REACT_APP_RECIPIENT_MAIL="a@a.com,b@a.com,c@a.com"
```

and then i am retrieving those like as below

```
  let toArr;
  if (isDevelopmentMode()) {
    const mailList = process.env.REACT_APP_RECIPIENT_MAIL;
    console.log(mailList);
    toArr = mailList.split(',');
  } else {
    toArr = Array.isArray(to) ? to : [to];
  }
  const toAddrs = toArr.map(toAddr => ({
    emailAddress: {
      address: toAddr
    }
  }));
```

getting `undefined` at this line `console.log(mailList);` for **mailList** and i am not sure where i am doing wrong with the above code, Could any one please suggest any ideas on this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you stop the server and run npm start again after adding the env var?

Comment: many thanks for the quick response, it worked after did `npm start`

Comment: Cool, I also wrote it as an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the newly added env variables to be available, you need to stop React server and start it again with `npm start`.